# Having trouble with manipulating a vector within a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, reference

I need to define a vector of testmodes that I can then manipulate the values of through various methods.

Here is how I define the TestMode class:

```
class TestMode{
public:
    TestMode(int val, int jamramaddr){
        value=val;
        jamramaddress=jamramaddr;
    }
    int getAddr(void){
        return jamramaddress;
    }
    void setValue(int val){
        value=val;
    }
    int getValue(void){
        return value;
    }
private:
    int value;
    int jamramaddress;
};
```

Pretty simple.

I then have a TestModeGroup class to perform actions on the vector of testmodes that I have created. That class looks like this:

```
class TestModeGroup{
public:
    TestModeGroup(const std::vector<TestMode> &TestModes){
        TestModeVector=TestModes;
    }
    //Compare the given jamramaddress against the known jamramaddress of the given testmode. If it is a match then update the testmode value
    void compareAndStore(TestMode &TM){
        int TM_address=TM.getAddr();
        if(TM_address==JamRamAddress){
            output("Match found! Old TM value %d", TM.getValue());
                TM.setValue(JamRamData);
            output("New TM value %d", TM.getValue());
        }
    }
    //Commit the given testmode to the jamram with the latest known value
    void writeTmBitToJamRam(TestMode &TM){
        JamRamAddress=TM.getAddr();
        JamRamData=TM.getValue();
        apg_jam_ram_set(JamRamAddress,JamRamData);
    }
    //running TestModeGroupObject.store(address, data) will find which test mode that jamram address is for and set the appropriate test mode value for later printing.
    //This is meant to be used in conjuction with the Excel spreadsheet method of entering test modes
    void store(int address, int data){
            JamRamAddress= address;
            JamRamData   = data;
            output("Current JamRamAddress = %d JamRamData = %d", JamRamAddress, JamRamData);
            apg_jam_ram_set(JamRamAddress,JamRamData);
            for(std::vector<TestMode>::iterator it = TestModeVector.begin(); it!=TestModeVector.end(); ++it){
                compareAndStore(*it);
            }
    }
    //Running TestModeGroupObject.load() will commit all test mode changes to the jamram for test modes that are part of that object
    void load(void){
            for(std::vector<TestMode>::iterator it = TestModeVector.begin(); it!=TestModeVector.end(); ++it){
                writeTmBitToJamRam(*it);
            }
    }
    int getTMVal(TestMode &TM){
        return TM.getValue();
    }
private:
    int JamRamAddress;
    int JamRamData;
    std::vector<TestMode> TestModeVector;
};
```

Here's how I defined the vector:

```
TestMode adm_testmodes[] = {TM_TWINWL,TM_TWINBL,ON_2WL,ON_2BL,WV_S1X,WV_S0X,TM_PCHG_RH_3,TM_PCHG_RH_2,TM_PCHG_RH_1,TM_PCHG_RH_0,TM_PCHG_RH_BYP,TM_PCHG_SF_3,TM_PCHG_SF_2,TM_PCHG_SF_1,TM_PCHG_SF_0,TM_PCHG_SF_BYP,
    TM_PCHG_V04_3,TM_PCHG_V04_2,TM_PCHG_V04_1,TM_PCHG_V04_0,TM_PCHG_V04_BYP,TM_SA_DIS,TM_TS_NEGSLOPE,TM_TRIM_4,TM_TRIM_3,TM_TRIM_2,TM_TRIM_1,TM_TRIM_0,TM_TSSLP_2,TM_TSSLP_1,TM_TSSLP_0,
    TM_WRV_N_2,TM_WRV_N_1,TM_WRV_N_0,TM_SAGAIN_EN,TM_REFTRIM_EN,TM_READ_DONE_OPT_EN,EnableCore_Read,SA_4,TM_OC_2,TM_OC_1,TM_OC_0,TM_WRLC_4,TM_WRLC_3,TM_WRLC_2,TM_WRLC_1,TM_WRLC_0,
    TM_WRHC_4,TM_WRHC_3,TM_WRHC_2,TM_WRHC_1,TM_WRHC_0,TM_FTOP_3,TM_FTOP_2,TM_FTOP_1,TM_FTOP_0,TM_RISE_1,TM_RISE_0,TM_WRH_3,TM_WRH_2,TM_WRH_1,TM_WRH_0,TM_SET_4,TM_SET_3,TM_SET_2,TM_SET_1,TM_SET_0,
    TM_REFSTART,TM_REFSEL_1,TM_REFSEL_0,TM_REFSL_5,TM_REFSL_4,TM_REFSL_3,TM_REFSL_2,TM_REFSL_1,TM_REFSL_0,TM_REFSH_5,TM_REFSH_4,TM_REFSH_3,TM_REFSH_2,TM_REFSH_1,TM_REFSH_0,TM_READ_DONE_ADD,
    TM_READ_DONE_OPT,TM_READ_DONE_5,TM_READ_DONE_4,TM_READ_DONE_3,TM_SAGAIN_1,TM_SAGAIN_0,TM_REFR_5,TM_REFR_4,TM_REFR_3,TM_REFR_2,TM_REFR_1,TM_REFR_0   
};

std::vector<TestMode> ADM_TMs (adm_testmodes, adm_testmodes + sizeof(adm_testmodes) / sizeof(TestMode));

TestModeGroup ADM_TestModeGroup(ADM_TMs);
```

So far so good. I can directly access all of the TestModes that are defined, change the value and have that change persist everywhere. The problem comes when I try to run the "store" function within the TestModeGroup class. It seems that I have a local copy of the TestModes that gets updated, but not the original TestMode. I'm sure that this is a pretty simple problem but I'm struggling. C++ is not my specialty, and OOP even less so.

Here's a quick example for a dummy testmode I created:

```
output("DUMMY_TESTMODE Initial Value: %d", DUMMY_ADM_TestModeGroup.getTMVal(DUMMY_TESTMODE));
DUMMY_TESTMODE.setValue(1);
output("DUMMY_TESTMODE Set to 1 Value: %d", DUMMY_ADM_TestModeGroup.getTMVal(DUMMY_TESTMODE));
DUMMY_TESTMODE.setValue(0);
output("DUMMY_TESTMODE Set to 0 Value: %d", DUMMY_ADM_TestModeGroup.getTMVal(DUMMY_TESTMODE));
DUMMY_ADM_TestModeGroup.store(22,1);
output("DUMMY_TESTMODE Set to 1 Value: %d", DUMMY_ADM_TestModeGroup.getTMVal(DUMMY_TESTMODE));
```

doing the .setValue works fine, but doing the .store does not. When I print out the value it comes back as 0. Within the .store function I do a printout, though, and that gives the right value of 1. Somehow I think I am simply altering a copy of the original vector, but I just can't figure it out. I've been driving myself crazy and nobody I've talked to knows enough about C++ to help. Does anybody have any insight as to where I've screwed up?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing TestModeGroup class:

```
class TestModeGroup{
public:
    TestModeGroup(const std::vector<TestMode> &TestModes) : TestModeVector(TestModes)
    {}

    // ...

    std::vector<TestMode> & TestModeVector;
};
```

If you want vector modifications done inside class to be applied to the original value passed to the constructor, you need to store a reference to the original object. Let me know if this helped :)

Comment: I can't even compile if I make that change. "'TestModeVector' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list"

Comment: You have to use initializer list in constructor:

`TestModeGroup(const std::vector<TestMode> &TestModes) : TestModeVector(TestModes){}`